# Animation in top down 2d

Tags: animation

How is this usually done? Especially when the character might need to use different animations, for instance at his hands and legs. I noticed some skeletal animation solutions but they were only applicable to platformer games. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think skeletal animation wouldn't work?

Comment: I just haven't seen any such examples yet. I am not talking about real top down right above the head but the birds eye version. The body parts are not really supposed to just rotate on one plane, they look different when the character is facing at different directions.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused what perspective exactly you want. Could you add an example image?

Comment: Something like this : http://gotymedia.gamespy.com/2005/images/screens/gba/minishcap.jpg

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67449/how-should-i-handle-sprite-creation-for-customizable-2d-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations like in the Minishcap that you showed as an example are generally done frame by frame because rotated body parts just would not look right at that perspective. You could experiment by drawing frame difference frames (i.e. your animation frames aren't full pictures of the character, they just show the difference between the last frame and the current frame, sort of like how videos work), to save space, although this could be negligible depending on the size of the character.

Generally, unless the game's perspective can make other approaches work, 2D animation is done frame by frame.

Comment: I thought so I just wondered if theres a smart workaround. ://Thx