# How can I change the gear of my 2D character?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to change the clothes of a 2D character(it's a 2D Windows Phone game) without creating new animations for that character? I want that the player can change the clothes of the character, but the character animations(for example walking, jumping, attacking) should rest the same. The clothes won't affect the character's animations.

I create my animations in Anime Studio Pro. Is it possible to change the clothes without creating new walking, jumping and attacking animations for every single dress?

Comment: [See also](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67449/how-should-i-handle-sprite-creation-for-customizable-2d-characters).

Comment: How does "3D Skeletal system for 2D animation" work? I know that I need to create a 3D character instead of a 2D character, but I don't understand why it is not necessary to create new walking, jumping and attacking animations for every single dress? Which software can I use to create such animations?