# 2D character generation

Tags: art, content-generation

I am creating a 2D game for mobile phones. It's in pixel style. Now I want the player to be able to create his own character based on givin items like: Hair, Eyes, Skin, Clothes, etc. (like in Starbound for example)

What is the best way to achive that. Should I create everything as a single texture with all frames of the animation of it (like a moving hair and clothes) and after the creation of the character, put those together to a single sprite with the giving items and frames? Or do you guys have any better ideas?

I am thankfull for every piece of help!

EDIT

Actually I did not started programming the character generation yet.
I am creating a RPG and want the players to be able to create individual characters (also with armor contents). Just kind a like in Starbound.

What I want from you guys are the best ways to realize such a system. With best I mean fast, simple and safe.

Comment: This is extremely opinion based as there's no "right" way to do mechanics like this. What you suggest isn't too uncommon but you probably wouldn't put all the frames into one texture (just because it'd be hard to programmatically add new pieces and back them into the final sprite later). It'd just be a simple carousel UI thing where every choice would be a different image.

Comment: This question would more useful and on-topic if you described a bit more what you'd want the system to do, especially if you've made some progress already.

Comment: Edited Question, more needed?

Comment: There is another duplicate of this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128671/animating-2d-character-which-can-wear-items/