# 2D Armor/Weapon System (Paperdolling)

Tags: 2d, rendering, sprites, spritesheet

I´m currently working on a 2D RPG where you should be able to compose your character from diffrent armor/weapon parts. For example the character can wear a "wooden helmet" and a "chain armor".

One technique I discovered is the so called "paperdolling" where you split every component (helmet, body armor, legs, weapon ...) into its own spritesheet and draw it on top of a naked base sprite.

However im not really sure how I can handle the following requirement:
I want to be able to use the same weapon sprite for diffrent poses / attacks. First I thought of some kind of "mount system" where I use a specific color to mark my "anchor points" on the sprites and generate some sort of metadata file which I can load into my game (maybe its similar to bone animations?). With this approach I know the anchor point(s) for every sprite and to which sprite they belong.

1. Do you think this is a sensible approach ?
2. Are there other techniques I could use to get the same results ?

Comment: [I recommend against questions that ask "is my approach good/sensible/etc"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2808/39518) because strangers on the Internet like us are not really the arbiters of this. The real test is whether your approach handles the use cases you care about most in your game, and you are the expert there. It sounds like you have two workable solutions in mind (aligning sprites at per-frame offsets, or using a skeletal animation bone hierarchy to move the sprites around). So I'd recommend picking the one you like and trying it. Ask here if you run into trouble with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating 2d character which can wear items?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128671/animating-2d-character-which-can-wear-items)