# How can I bake 2D sprites in Godot at runtime?

Tags: sprites, godot

I would like to use the technique described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67449/how-should-i-handle-sprite-creation-for-customizable-2d-characters) to create a player sprite with unlimited clothing and equipment options (like in Stardew Valley).

To elaborate: I want to have a sprite sheet for the player sprite's body, some number of sprite sheets for clothing items the player sprite could wear, and some number of sprite sheets for tools the player sprite could carry. Once the (human) player has selected the desired body, clothing, and tool, I want to layer and bake the chosen items into one sprite sheet.

In Godot Engine, how is this kind of baking accomplished at runtime?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you let the player select a series of sprite sheets. And there is some order in which you overlay them to create the sprite sheet of the player.

---

### Image manipulation at runtime

We can create an [`Image`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_image.html):

```
var image = Image.new() 
image.create(256,256,false,Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

*Change `256,256` with the appropriate size.*

There the format is important. You want a format that has an alpha channel, otherwise, you will not be able to draw with transparency.

---

Now we need the image we are going to draw (the first sprite sheet). We can use `load` or `preload` to get it. For example:

```
var icon := preload("res://icon.png")
```

We usually import as textures, but we want an image. So we use [`get_data()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_texture.html#class-texture-method-get-data):

```
var source := preload("res://icon.png").get_data()
```

Then we can draw it with [`blit_rect`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_image.html#class-image-method-blit-rect):

```
image.blit_rect(source, Rect2(Vector2.ZERO, source.get_size()), Vector2.ZERO)
```

There the [`Rect2`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rect2.html) is the source area (the area of the image we are drawing that we want to draw) which goes from `Vector2.ZERO` to the size of the image. The other `Vector2.ZERO` is the position where we want to draw it.

Now the idea is that you will do that for all the sprite sheets that you need to draw.

---

**Note**: depending on the format of the image you want to draw, you may have to convert it first:

```
source.convert(Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

Also, usually, the images are imported in a compressed format that cannot be converted directly, and thus you would have to decompress first:

```
source.decompress()
source.convert(Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

If the `blit_rect` line is giving you problems, try that.

---

### Using a Viewport texture

If you found the above approach too limiting. You can add a `Viewport` with a `Camera2D`. Then to get the texture from the `Viewport`, you can use `viewport.get_texture()` (and, of course, you can get an `Image` from it with `.get_data()`).

Thus, you can add to the `Viewport` anything you want to draw. Which means that you can add multiple nodes to compose the image, with their transforms and modulations. Or it could be a single one which uses the methods described in [Custom drawing in 2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/custom_drawing_in_2d.html), or [CanvasItem shaders](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/shading_reference/canvas_item_shader.html) (For example, you may allow the user to do a hue rotation of a sprite sheet, implemented in a shader). Or combinations of those techniques.

---

### Creating sprite frames for animation

Once you are done, you can create an ImageTexture from the `Image`, like this:

```
image_texture = ImageTexture.new()
image_texture.create_from_image(image)
```

Since we are talking of sprite sheet, we can create `AtlasTexture`s:

```
func get_texture_frame(row, column):
    var t = AtlasTexture.new()
    t.atlas = image_texture
    t.region = (
            column * SPRITE_WIDTH,
            row * SPRITE_HEIGHT,
            SPRITE_WIDTH,
            SPRITE_HEIGHT
        )
    return t
```

Then we can add the `AtlasTexture`s to a [`SpriteFrames`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spriteframes.html) with `add_frame` to use them in an `AnimatedSprite`.

Creating a `SpriteFrames` in code looks something like this:

```
var frames := SpriteFrames.new()
frames.add_animation("animation_name")
frames.set_animation_speed("animation_name", frames_per_second)
frames.add_frame("animation_name", get_texture_frame(0, 0))
frames.add_frame("animation_name", get_texture_frame(0, 1))
# …
```

---

### Persistent storage

If you want to save an `Image`, you can use `save_png`.

If you want to save the `ImageTexture` or the `AtlasTexture`s or the `SpriteFrames`, you can use [`ResourceSaver.save`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourcesaver.html#class-resourcesaver-method-save). I suggest to use path in `user://`, see [Data Paths](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html).

To load them again, you can use `load` or [`ResourceLoader.load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceloader.html#class-resourceloader-method-load).

Comment: What a thorough answer! I haven't been able to try it out yet, but I expect it to work. Thank you!